# Can I deduce HTML POST data from the front end?

Tags: html, post

please may I have a little help I'm stuck not being able to google for a solution because of very common words.

There is a web page that uses POST to send data to a page on a subdomain when a button is clicked.

I need to recreate a button and send the same information.

My question is: Is it possible just by looking at the page (and the console??) when you click the button, to observer what happens and recreate/implement the same POST method?

Can I say for example: It does this, therefore I need this code to do the same thing?

Or is it not possible to reverse engineer? Will I have to seek help form the web page developer (not really an option in this case).

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly possible to inspect the request and reverse engineer this. You can use tools like the developer console in your [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools)/[Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/console) browser (press F12), and tools like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) to simulate requests. Also inspect the form and eventual javascript events attached to the button.

Comment: Thank you. The part I found most helpful was to inspect the form. I did find the code I was after right there in the html. SO inspecting the form was the most helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I'm happy I could help! Remember to either vote for helpful post, or accept as answer, if you found my post helpful.